# Show uniform convergence of series

Tags: convergence-divergence

Show that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (j+1)x^j$ converges uniformly for x $\in$ any compact subset of (-1,1).

Using the ratio test, I got: $\frac{j+2}{j+1}x^j$. However, I don't know how to compare this to 1...Is there another method, or am I missing something?

Comment: This series doesn't converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$; it converges uniformly on every compact subset of $(-1,1)$, though.

Comment: Ok, edited question

Comment: Would compactness be equivalent to a closed interval?

Comment: No, but compactness is equivalent to being a closed subset of $(-1,1)$. It would suffice to prove that the series converges uniformly on every interval of the form $[-\ell, \ell]$ for $0 \le \ell < 1$.

Comment: Ok, thank you...Still not sure how to use the convergence test results. It is clear that $x^j$ will be < 1, but I don't know about the fraction.

Comment: Notice that $|x|^j \le \ell^j$ for all $x \in [-\ell, \ell]$, and try to combine it with the fact that $\frac{j + 2}{j + 1}$ is bounded.

Comment: Wouldn't the supremum of the fraction be something slightly greater than 1, so can that still guarantee the product is <1?

Comment: You'll need to use the fact that $\ell^j \to 0$.

Comment: Hmm, but if we are using limsup, then wouldn't the supremum and hence its limit be something other than 0?

Comment: No; the $\limsup$ is much smaller than the $\sup$. Try to compute $$\lim_{j \to \infty} \left(\frac{j + 2}{j + 1}\right) \ell^j$$ and convince yourself that it is, in fact, $0$.

Comment: Ok, I see that this is 0, but how can we take out the supremum part? Are we using the fact that the limit and limsup are equal when we have convergence? I think I am just confused...must the limsup eventually be equal to the limit?

Comment: How is $\left(\frac{j+2}{j+1}\right)\ell^j$ related to the question?

Comment: It is from the ratio test

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ in $(0,1)$. For every $x$ in $[-R,R]$ and every $n$,
$$
\left|\sum_{j\geqslant n}(j+1)x^j\right|\leqslant\varepsilon_R(n),
$$
where
$$
\varepsilon_R(n)=\sum_{j\geqslant n}(j+1)R^j.
$$
The question is to show that for every $R\lt1$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\varepsilon_R(n)=0.
$$
Can you show this?